# Shorcut to storing incremented values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

this is my code currently:

```
let array = [`1 (1).jgp`,`1 (2).jgp`,`1 (3).jgp`,`1 (4).jgp`,`1 (5).jgp`,`1 (6).jgp`,`1 (7).jgp`,`1 (8).jgp`,`1 (9).jgp`,`1 (10).jgp`,`1 (11).jgp`]
//rest of the code
```

Is there a more efficent way of storing the data?

I have tried:

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    let array = [`1`+(i)+`.jgp`]
};
//rest of the code
```

But, then when I tried to call array it returned: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined
    at :1:1

I also tried:

```
let array = [`1`+(i = 0; i < 12; i++)+`.jgp`]
//rest of the code
```

But that returned: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Or how I can make this code more efficient. 
Thanks,

Comment: *"Or how I can make this code more efficient."* Define "efficient." Your first code block is by far the most *efficient* in terms of speed, not that it's at all likely to matter... If you mean memory use, you'd have to show how the array is used. If you mean code size/complexity, what criteria do you want to apply?

Comment: why did you use backticks as if you were going to use Template Literals, but then add the strings as if you were using normal strings? Template literals allow you to do stuff like ` ``1 (${i}).jpg`` `, you don't need to add strings, that's the entire point of them.

Comment: why do you use back ticks for strings? the use of template literals is in strings without a variable not advisable, because of the overhead to parse the content.

Comment: just an other hint, maybe you consider to change the naming structure for the images ...

Comment: Not sure if I should flag this too broad or suggest codereview.SE. We don't really do "fix this code" questions on any network. You should boil this down to the actual question, "how do I iterate 12 times" basically.

Comment: @Jhoverit your comment is useless. the question has already been answered, move on. have a good day.

Comment: @user37 actually it's not useless. Please do some reading on how to use StackOverflow.

Comment: nope your comment was useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the array using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const arr = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => `1 (${i + 1}).jgp`);

console.log(arr);
```

Although a simple for loop would work as well:

```js
const array = []; // declare an empty array

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    array.push(`1 (${i}).jgp`); // push each item to the array
};

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks. I also have a follow-up question. I am using your first part of the answer, which is working perfectly. I also need to find a way to make this array infinite such that it would contain the "1 (1-10).jgp" and then another set of the same array within it. Like so: `1 (1).jgp`,`1 (2).jgp`,`1 (3).jgp`,`1 (4).jgp`,`1 (5).jgp`,`1 (6).jgp`,`1 (7).jgp`,`1 (8).jgp`,`1 (9).jgp`,`1 (10).jgp`,`1 (10).jgp`,`1 (1).jgp`,`1 (2).jgp`,`1 (3).jgp`,`1 (4).jgp` and etc... Can you please help me with this? Many thanks!

Comment: You might want to use a generator for this. However, since it's a new issue, please open a new question. And describe what you want in much more details. Also, describe the purpose of this.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more efficent way of storing the data?

You mean store in such a way that **less storage is required?**

Store in this format

```
var arrayObj = {
  template : "{{i}} ({{i}}).jgp",
  startIndex : 1,
  endIndex : 10
};
```

> Or how I can make this code more efficient.

If how much storage is used is not the concern, then simply use a simple iterator

```
var array = [];
for( var counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++ )
{
  array.push(  "1 ( " + counter + " ).jgp" );
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't very clear - storage is not a concern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    array.push(`1 (`+i+`).jgp`);
};
console.log(array);
```

Comment: There's no point to those template literals, just use string literals (or use template literals correctly).